# how to run yeoman generator-angular commands in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, ionic-framework

I am lookig on generator-angular powered by yeoman ,It generate not only an angular base app but also other things like routes controller filter directive etc with the help of sub generator.

I am making an Ionic app ,As I know Ionic is based on Angularjs ,so while developping it I have to create routes ,controller and other stuff manually.

There is a [Ionic Framework generator](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic) which genrate a Ionic base project but It does not create angular specific task like controller and routes .
 Is there any way we can do that in ionic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Generator (`npm install generator-angular -g`) seems to be able to scaffold into an ionic app, but it puts the files in the wrong place. Default ionic apps put everything into www/. All of the generators expect things to be in app/.

The Ionic Framework Generator you refer to sets things up to use app/, and the angular generator seems to work ok with it.

Comment: You can change the path using [the options](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#output)